# Listing and Detail pages in Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to extend a report that has a listing of employees with basic performance data.  I'm looking to add a page on each employee that shows more in depth analysis. Ideally, this would be a page or half a page of details.  I'm wondering how I can achieve this.  I'm imagining, a variation of subreports, but Crystal seems very tabular and linear to me- a table print out of an SQL feed. 
I'm imagining something like that.  Ideally, with hyperlinks to a detail page for each person in the overview.  Is this possible with Crystal?  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, "hyperlinks" to subreports are possible. When adding the subreport, check the box labelled *On-demand subreport (similar to a hyperlink)*.

[image]

As with all subreports, be sure to set the table links and parameters correctly, such that you only get information for the person in question.

Comment: I actually left out a major detail. This is to be a pdf.  Is this still the same process? @4444

Comment: @user1093111 No. This would only work when viewed as an RPT file in a Report Viewer. If it *must* be a PDF, you'd be better off putting the information in a Group Footer where it can be visible all the time.